# What is a set whose elements consist of all relations from A to B? and a couple more questions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations, set-partition

I have an exam prep sheet on questions to "ponder" about. I've read the book for the class, and I can't seem to find the answers to these.

Can anybody give me a hand with these?

1. What is a set whose elements consist of all relations from A to B?
2. If R is an equivalence relation on A, then what is the equivalence class [a] of an element a.
3. If a relation R is an equivalence relation on A, then there is a particular partition on A associated with R, what is the partition and how do you find it?
4. If P is a partition of a set A, then what is the equivalence relation Rp corresponding to P? What is the rule for that equivalence relation?

What I think are the answers:

1. No idea
2. the equivalence class represents all related subsets of elements from R?
3. there exists a collection of non empty subsets that which cover all of A?
4. I have no idea.

Comment: Do you know the set-theoretic definition of relation between two sets? Do you know the definition of equivalence class? If so, write them and check if they match your (1) and (2).

Comment: @ G. Sassateli A binary relation from A to B is a subset of A X B.  So in that case would the answer be the set of AXB?

Comment: I don't know what "set of $A\times B$" means, but if it stands for "the parts of $A\times B$" = "the set of subsets of $A\times B$" = $\mathcal P(A\times B)$, then yes.

Comment: @G. Sassatelli What does P(AXB) stand for?

Comment: As for 4) what are the properties needed for an equivalence relation?

Comment: @cicero866 Do you know what the set of all subsets of a set is?

Comment: @Sentinel135 I believe its the powerset?

Comment: Power set hmmm. So if we have a set $X$, wouldn't we want to define the power set of $X$ as $\mathcal P(X)$?

Comment: @sentinel135 i'm lost. It says P is a partition, but now P is the powerset? I know that for an equivalence relation we need a relation thats reflexive, transitive and symmetric. But I'm not quite sure how that answers number 4...

Comment: I'm answering the question that you had for G.Sassatelli, notice that $\mathcal P()$ is different then the partition of $A$ known as $P$. While they are both sets of subsets of a set they are in no sense the same. $P$ is a set such that $\bigcup _{p\in P} p = A$ and $\bigcap _{p\in P}p= \emptyset$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55249/discussion-between-sentinel135-and-cicero866).